# Printer temps are displaying on top of each other on Ender 3 v2 running Marlin 2.1.2

Tags: marlin, firmware

I just finished flashing Marlin 2.1.2 on my Ender 3 V2 printer. I had some difficulty flashing the screen from my SD card, but once I formatted the card to 4096 FAT32 and added the both Marlin `...Creality/Ender-3/CrealityV422/LCD/private` and `...Creality/Ender-3/CrealityV422/DWIN_SET` directories to it, it worked.

Now however, I see that the numbers are updating and displaying over each other. In the picture below, the nozzle temp is 22 stacked on a 20. When it rises, it'll show all 3 temps on the same space. The bottom row are the default question-marks stacked on the x/y/z coordinates.

[image]

For the compilation, I used PlatformIO. I basically followed this video exactly:

The main difference being I stopped the tutorial after setting the LCD controller at ProUI, since it was my preferred build.

[Here is a link to my configuration files and my bin file](https://ufile.io/3a4v7ak3), in case anyone alse wants to reproduce this locally.

Comment: Please explain why the LCD looks so different from the one in the video (https://youtu.be/7i7PnBZ6cnM?t=1401) (is that caused by the phrase you refer to by stopping with the tutorial?).

Comment: Yes, in the video he goes through multiple different UI versions. I liked the proUI one best, so I stopped once he showed that. The time stamp is 21:09 for ProUI. My icons DO look a little different though, but I don't know why.